# Can I write spring java tests in groovy?

Tags: spring, groovy, junit, dependency-injection

I have a junit test in the spring environment with dependency injection in java.

I'm interested in groovy and would like to write my tests with it.

How would look the following test in groovy?

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(value = "/META-INF/spring/context.xml")
public class DITestJava {

    @Inject
    WriteController wc;
    @Inject
    ReadController rc;

    @Test
    public void diTest() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(wc);
        Assert.assertNotNull(rc);

        wc.doConfig();
        rc.printConfig();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the same annotations in your groovy file. As long as groovy is in your class path, it should just work.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you know if I can use annotations too in a dialect like the behaviour driven groovy languages which have the scenario/given/when/then. Where would I add the RunWith and ContextConfiguration annotation?

Comment: Yes, I use them with the Spock framework.  In this case the tests extend `spock.lang.Specification` and run with the JUnit runner.

Comment: downvoting  because this didn't actually answer the question